# Save multiple records in multiple tables after save model in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have the followings tables:

1. tbl_project(**id**, description)
2. tbl_operation(**id**, **project_id**, name)
3. tbl_itemType(**id**, **operation_id**, name)
4. tbl_item(**id**, **itemType_id**, name, unit, price)

I wanna when i create a new project, it adds some operations in **tbl_operation** and then adds some itemTypes to **tbl_itemType** and then adds some items in **tbl_item**. How can i do it in **afterSave()** behavior of project's model?

I read the following link, but i don't know is it possible to do by this?

[esaverelatedbehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/esaverelatedbehavior/)

Answer (score 1):

just create a function in your `ProjectModel`

```
public function afterSave()
{
   $operation_model = new Operation();
   $operation_model->setAttributes($YOUR_DATA);
   $operation_model->save(); // create your operation

   // same goes for every other data you want to save

    return parent::afterSave(); // keep the chain
}
```

Comment: to add some **itemTypes** in **tbl_itemType** i need **operation_id** attribute, How can i get **operation_id** of saved operation?

Comment: if `$operation_model->save()` has succeeded, primary key will be populated, so `$operation_model->id` will be available for you to use with other model saves

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the relations. This approach will only work if the respective relation contains only the models to be saved. In your controller have

```
$project->operations = array(/*your operations*/);
```

In turn each operation model could also have the related `itemTypes`

```
$operation->itemTypes = array(/*itemTypes for this operation*/)
```

And lastly each `itemType` could have the related `items`.

And in your `afterSave` for operations have

```
public function afterSave() {
    foreach ($this->operation as $op) {
        $op->project_id = $model->id;
        $op->save();
    }
    return parent::afterSave();
}
```

For the `afterSave` for the `Operation` and `ItemType` classes should in turn save the related `ItemType`s and `Item`s respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Better use  afterSave() function , i think it will work for you